# Docker-py: Is there a way to pass a callback function to a container running in 'detach' mode?

Tags: python, dockerpy

I am running a container with [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) in Python. Similar to the docs:

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run('bfirsh/reticulate-splines', detach=True)
```

The container performs some tasks and saves a `.json` file to a shared volume.
Everything is working fine except that I do not know how to catch the container exit when running in the background.
More specifically, my question is the following:

*"Is there a way in docker-py to pass a callback function to a container running in detach mode?"*

I want to access the saved `.json` **on exit** and avoid using ugly statements like `time.sleep()` or iterating while the `status is running`.
From the docs it does not seem possible. Do you have any workaround to share?

Comment: Might there be a way to use Docker Events (which I'd never noticed before): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events ?  If the docker-py library doesn't support this, maybe there is other Python code out there that does. Just a thought but probably a long shot.  My guess is that you're not going to find a solution that avoids polling the status of the container.  Best of luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks. The events APIs look fine. They are not supported by docker-py, though. I guess the way to go is to start a thread and iterating over the `container.status` until it exits and then perform the post-run tasks within that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, I adopted the following solution using threads.

```py
import docker
import threading

def run_docker():
    """ This function run a Docker container in detached mode and waits for completion. 
        Afterwards, it performs some tasks based on container's result.
    """

    docker_client = docker.from_env()
    container = docker_client.containers.run(image='bfirsh/reticulate-splines', detach=True)

    result = container.wait()
    container.remove()

    if result['StatusCode'] == 0:
        do_something()  # For example access and save container's log in a json file
    else:
        print('Error. Container exited with status code', result['StatusCode'])


def main():
    """ This function start a thread to run the docker container and 
        immediately performs other tasks, while the thread runs in background.
    """

    threading.Thread(target=run_docker, name='run-docker').start()
    # Perform other tasks while the thread is running.
```